# perform Segue from filtered tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I built a UISearchBar for my tableView which filters the user Names... so far so good but now I want to perform a segue from a cell of the tableView when it's filtered, but as soon as I click on a cell I get back to the originViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        print("Dismiss completed")
        let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
        self.messagesController?.showChatControllerForUser(user)
        }
    searchController.isActive = false
    }
```

searchBar functions

```
func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func isFiltering() -> Bool {
    return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filtered = users.filter({( user : User) -> Bool in
        return (user.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Edit:

```
func showChatControllerForUser(_ user: User) {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    chatLogController.user = user
    navigationController?.pushViewController(chatLogController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Why are you running `dismiss`? That is why the current controller is being dismissed.

Comment: Insted of Dismiss() you have to use performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:) Inside didSelectRowAt IndexPath. Use the same identifier which you have set on Segue from you FilteredTableViewController

Comment: I use it to dismiss the complete tableViewSection and go to the messagesController @GaloTorresSevilla it works if the tableView is unfiltered, only if it is filtered it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: But that's what I'm doing... I don't use a Storyboard so I can't performSegues, that's why I put "self.messagesController?.showChatControllerForUser(user)" there @BhavikModi

Comment: Than, your question is misleading as you have mentioned ** ... so far so good but now I want to perform a segue from a cell of the tableView when it's filtered ... **. Updated your question with proper details.